# Error backoffice.js:128 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null(…)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Al utilizar la funcion `replace()` me sale este error. La estoy utilizando porque estoy generando codigo html con valores introducidos del usuario con un boton.

El problema es que si el usuario introduce comillas dobles (") o simple (') no se genera el codigo correctamente.

Con la funcion ``` replacre("'", "``") ``` puedo remplazar esas comillas simples

pero me sale este error

> backoffice.js:128 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace'
>   of null(…)

Inserto la parte del codigo a ver si veis el error.

```js
function modificarSugerencia(id){
     $.get("modules/backoffice/sugerencias/leer_sugerencia.php?idSugerencia=" + id, function(data){
        if(data)
        {
            json = JSON.parse(data);

            //console.log(data);
            console.log(json.sugerencia.CUERPO_SUGERENCIA);
            

            url="modules/backoffice/sugerencias/rellenadoSugerencias.php";
            urlReturn="modules/backoffice/sugerencias/gestion_sugerencias.php";
            var boxhtml ="";
            boxhtml+="<form action='' name='comunicationUpdate' id='comunicationUpdate' method='post'";
            boxhtml+="<div id='box-modificar-comunicado' class='capa-fondo-caja capa-fondo-caja-backoffice centered-absolute'>";
            boxhtml+="<div class='header-caja-fondo-backoffice'>"

            boxhtml+="<h2><span class='icon-document-edit size-icons-table-backoffice'></span>Modificación sugerencia</h2>";
            boxhtml+="</div>";

            boxhtml+="<div id='form-main'>";
            boxhtml+="<p class='asunto'>Asunto:";
            boxhtml+="<input name='asunto' type='text' class='feedback-input' placeholder='Asunto' id='asunto' value='"+json.sugerencia.ASUNTO.replace("'","`")+"' />";
            boxhtml+="</p>";

            boxhtml+="<p class='fechas'>Descripcion mejora:";    
            boxhtml+="<input name='cuerpoSugerencia' type='text' class='feedback-input' value='"+json.sugerencia.CUERPO_SUGERENCIA.replace("'","`")+"' />";
            boxhtml+="</p>";

            boxhtml+="<p class='text'>Respuesta:";
            boxhtml+="<input name='respuesta' type='text' class='feedback-input' id='comment' value='"+json.sugerencia.RESPUESTA.replace("'","`")+"' placeholder='Comunicado'>";
            boxhtml+="</p>";
```

Comment: ¿cual seria exactamente la linea 128? El error te esta diciendo que `json.sugerencia.ALGO` es `null` y por eso no puedes hacer `json.sugerencia.ALGO.replace`

Comment: He encontrado el error. Es justamente lo que acabas de decir. Estaba intentando hacer un "Replace" de algo que estaba en `null`. El problema es que aveces esta null y otras no... sabes como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar errores con datos `null` debes verificarlos

Javascript :

```
if ( typeof(json.sugerencia.ASUNTO) !== "undefined" &&  json.sugerencia.ASUNTO !== null ) {
       boxhtml+="<div id='form-main'>";
       boxhtml+="<p class='asunto'>Asunto:";
       boxhtml+="<input name='asunto' type='text' class='feedback-input' placeholder='Asunto' id='asunto' value='"+json.sugerencia.ASUNTO.replace("'","`")+"' />";
       boxhtml+="</p>";
}else {
      //Error
}
```

Comment: Gracias, solucionado.

Answer (score -1):

Para escapar las comillas simples o dobles debes usar `\`.  Ej:

```
replace("\'","´´")
```

Comment: Me parece que esto no está relacionado con el error que comenta el autor: `Cannot read property 'replace' of null(…)`.  Además, ¿por qué sería necesario escapar las comillas simples en tu ejemplo?

Comment: @Mariano entendí que el error salia por el replace